find which mapping and slot a key belongs to
How is it possible to know which mapping a key belongs to?
For storage mappings how is it possible to know if a key belongs to a mapping or another?
For example, there are 2 mappings on the contract (for example balances and allowances. And you got the key to an element inside of one of the mappings. How can you know which mapping does the key belong to and confirm it belongs to one of the 2 mappings?
For example, how do tools like evm storage or tenderly identify which variable holds which data. They are even able to name the variables.
I know state variables are stored in the order they are declared, but I am having trouble figuring out for mappings. And how can this be obtained using Web3js/Web3py.
Thank you.

Are the names and the types of the mappings known? And, the number of mappings from which the key to be searched, is specific i.e., 2?

Hi, its the balances mapping, address -> uint256. But I have no way to know where its been declared. Sometimes it mught be higher, or sometimes lower, depending on the contract

I just want to confirm that the key I got from the state change diff belongs to the balances mapping. Somehow tenderly and evm.storage can detect even the variable name

The way those tools work (I think) is that they execute the transaction and look at how the storage slot is calculated. For example if they find the storage slot calculated as keccak(uint256(someAddress) . uint256(0x00)), they know it's from the mapping saved at slot 0x00. Then looking at the source code of the contract they can figure out which variable it is.
Without running the transaction I don't think you can decide generally. However if your doubt is between balances, allowances, etc. and you know the calldata of the transaction, you can just try all the options.

I assume it mught be something like this so I marked it as valid. Not sure if they can detect sourcecontracts with no code verified, but I haven't tested. Is there a Python example for this code? as I think you are suggesting to try it by iteration, such as 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, until it matches the key? Something like that?

Yes, it's how I would do it, but I don't have an example

Thank you so much!
